# Using jquery to clone() an html table and all it's data including select's and their options and inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

On the td class "edit" i only want to show the span class "look" and strip the other select class option values and than import them into excel.

```
<tr class="proj_rec" data-id="4">
  <td class="proj_id">
    4                    </td>
  <td>
    Music in the stores                    </td>
  <td class="edit">
    <select class="touch" style="display: none;">
      <option value="13">Bloopers</option><option value="1">Customer Service</option><option value="2">DC</option><option value="3">Ecommerce</option><option value="4">Finance/Accounting</option><option value="5">Human Resources</option><option value="6">Inbound Logistics</option><option value="7">Information Systems</option><option value="14">Management</option><option value="8">Marketing</option><option value="9">Merchandising</option><option value="10">Property</option><option value="11">Rebuying</option><option value="12">Sales</option>                        </select>
    <span class="look">
      Sales                        </span>
  </td>
  <td class="edit">
    <select class="touch" style="display: none;">
      <option value="1">As is review</option><option value="2">Complete</option><option value="3">Development</option><option value="4">Implemented</option><option value="5">Not started</option><option value="6">To be design</option>                        </select>
    <span class="look">
      As is review                        </span>
  </td>
  <td class="edit">
    <select class="touch" style="display: none;">
      <option value="1"> Objective</option><option value="2"> People</option><option value="3"> Process</option><option value="4"> Systems</option>                        </select>
    <span class="look">
      Process                        </span>
  </td>
```

[image]

Right now I have these blanks showing up and I think it's due to it rendering all the options of the select class.

I tried a few options but to no avail. Here's where i'm at right now. It's removing the UI options after exporting and i'm still having the problem in excel like shown above in the image.

```
    <td><input type="button" id="dlink" onclick="tableToExcel('project_table', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel"></td>
            <a id="dlink"  style="display:none;"></a>

var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function (table, name, filename) {
        $('#'+table+' .touch').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().prepend($(this).val()); //if you want to keep the values.
        });
        $('#'+table+' .touch').remove();
        //if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
        document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
        document.getElementById("dlink").click();
        $('#'+table).remove();      
    }
})()
```

---

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
     var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function (table, name, filename) {
       $('#'+table+' .touch').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().text($(this).val()); //if you want to keep the values.
 });
        var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
        document.getElementById('dlink').href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        document.getElementById('dlink').download = filename;
        document.getElementById('dlink').click();
         $('#'+table+' .look').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().text($(this).text()); //get text from span and replace parent innerHtml with it
 });
     }
})()
```

Comment: you only want their values to show up? Not clear what you are expecting

Comment: The values that have been selected before the import yes, so the first row would be "Sales" and the next field would be "As in review", "Process". Only what's in the <span class="look">Sales</span> for each cell and all rows obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try wiping out the select and the span by simply using `text()` which would replace any html within each td with just text

```
 $('#'+table+' .touch').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().text($(this).val()); //if you want to keep the values.
 });
```

OR use the text from the span:

```
  $('#'+table+' .look').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().text($(this).text()); //get text from span and replace parent innerHtml with it
 });
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a go and let you know if it works for me. The thing that sucks is since i'm dynamically creating the content when a user pushes a button it builds all the html data inside the table. And then i push another button to export to excel. So.. set a JS variable with a DOM element and than remove the select boxes to not be there, and than create a DOM element which does not have those select boxes, push into excel.. All while keep the UI intact?  =]

Comment: If use a clone, ui would be left intact

Comment: i need the UI to be left intact, I only want the table data exported to excel which is the table data selected, not all the other options.

Comment: How exactly is that suppose to integrate into my existing code @charlietfl like so?

Comment: look at the bottom bit of my code and can you confirm i'm integrating it right but i'm getting adverse effects on the UI and still having trouble with Excel.

Comment: seems right ....be easier if could test on live demo in jsfiddle.net. If use the `.touch` code, the `.look` spans should be gone before the code for them fires, so shouldn't be needed. jQuery won't have error if they are gone already, just won't do anyhting and keep going with rest of code

Comment: For some reason i can't get it working, I even wrapped it in a JS function like so:  `function gd(){
  $('#'+table+' .touch').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().text($(this).text()); //get text from span and replace parent innerHtml with it
 });
}` and than just added the function into the var tableToExcel function.. no dice.  =/

Comment: make a demo in jsfiddle.net , will just comment out the excel stuff and mke sure html parsing is right

Comment: Does that fiddle not help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40973/discussion-between-cook-and-charlietfl)